# Unable to find neo4j-cypher-dsl version 1.9.M04 anywhere

Tags: maven, neo4j, spring-data, spring-data-neo4j, spring-data-graph

`org.springframework.data:spring-data-neo4j:2.2.1.RELEASE` depends on `neo4j-cypher-dsl:org.neo4j:1.9.M04` but I am unable to find this dsl artifact in any public mvn repositories. Any idea on where to get this jar?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Found this in neo4j repo here http://m2.neo4j.org/content/repositories/releases/org/neo4j/neo4j-cypher-dsl/1.9.M04/